# Yandex map API 2.1. Как получить северо-западную точку прямоугольника полученного из getBounds()?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как из getBounds() получить координаты северо-западного угла?

```
const om = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
const collection = {
  features,
  type: "FeatureCollection",
};

om.add(collection);

const omBounds = om.getBounds();
```

Comment: оно массив координат возвращает, вероятно вершин прямоугольника описывающего точки менеджера, и вероятно начинающегося с левого верхнего. ? Главное должно быть понятно. что это не видимая область карты, а минимальный прямоугольник, в который впихиваются все точки коллекции.

Comment: У меня есть коллекция фичей в них полигоны потом их добавляю в менеджер для получения минимального прямоугольника и у него найти северо-западные координаты и отцентровать карту по ним с зумом, но не могу найти северо-западные координаты( Может посмотреть в сторону области карты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getBounds()** возвращает юго-западную и северо-восточную координаты прямоугольника в виде массива. Просто возьмите нужные вам широту и долготу из этого значения для получения оставшихся координат:

```
var nordWest = [omBounds[1][0],omBounds[0][1]]
var southEast = [omBounds[0][0],omBounds[1][1]]
```